# Is it possible to keep activating a script in unity?

Tags: c#, android, button, unity-game-engine, scripting

I have a button in Unity 5, and it is loading a script to show the Google Leaderboard I've set up. However, after I press the button and leave the leaderboard, it doesn't open the leaderboard when I tap my button again. Is there a way to activate the script again?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Show us the script...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you scripts has already been loaded so if the leaderboard is display in Start() or Activate() then it makes sense it doesn't show up again.
Have the code that shows the leaderboard be in a function on the script like

```
public void ShowLeaderboard(){
     //Do whatever you need to do
}
```

Attach this script to the button or better, a parent of the button. Then the button's OnClick callback will be ShowLeaderboard.
You can have the script call it in the Start() function to, but generally you want to avoid relying on functionality of a script happening on load and nowhere else